# Simple query is slow in laravel (with paginate) but very fast in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I've looked at similar questions, and the answers I get is to put limit in my query, which I did.

Here is the query

```
  $sql = DB::table('inventorysku_tb as isku')
     ->leftJoin('inventorytrackingmodules_tb as itm', function ($join) {
        $join->where('itm.coID', '=', 4)
           ->whereBetween('itm.effectiveDate', ['2021-05-01', '2021-05-31'])
           ->on('itm.skuID', '=', 'isku.ID');
     })


  $sql->paginate(25);

  return $sql;
```

This query takes around 17 seconds to run, now if I run ->toSql() on the query above and paste it in phpmyadmin (changing the ? values)

```
select * 
from `inventorysku_tb` as `isku` 
    left join `inventorytrackingmodules_tb` as `itm` 
        on `itm`.`coID` = 4
        and `itm`.`effectiveDate` between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31'
        and `itm`.`skuID` = `isku`.`ID`
```

This one only takes 0.2 seconds to run in phpmyadmin...

That is all on the laravel code, there are no other codes above it...

Another weird thing is if I change to left join to inner join in laravel, the query is now fast (878 ms)..

Comment: Hey, so a few things you can try. Firstly you can use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), which will show you the queries run on each page and will make it easier for you to debug. Another thing, which may help is adding indexes on your tables.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on):
On clauses can be chained, e.g.

```
$join->on('contacts.user_id', '=', 'users.id') ->on('contacts.info_id', '=', 'info.id')
```

will produce the following SQL:

```
on contacts.user_id = users.id and contacts.info_id = info.id
```

so, for you case the code could be:

```
$sql = DB::table('inventorysku_tb as isku')
     ->leftJoin('inventorytrackingmodules_tb as itm', function ($join) {
        $join->on('itm.coID', '=', 4)
           ->on(function ($query){
                $query->whereBetween( 'itm.effectiveDate',['2021-05-01',
                   '2021-05-31']);
           ->on('itm.skuID', '=', 'isku.ID');
     })
```

this way, I think you could produce the same query that you used in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LEFT`.  Since you are limiting things in the `WHERE` it is a `JOIN`.

Add this to `itm`:  `INDEX(coID, skuID, effectiveDate)`